# Regarding unique factorization in a polynomial ring and irreducibles

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I believe I'm not correctly understanding the concept of unique factorization and irreducibles.

Consider $R = \mathbb{F}_7$ and $h \in R[x]$ where $h = x^4 + 4x^3 + 3x^2 + 5x + 6$. Now $h$ has the following factorizations:

$h_1 = (3x^2 + 3x + 4)(5x^2 + x + 5)$

and

$h_2 = (x^2 + x + 6)(x^2 + 3x + 1)$

All four of those quadratics are irreducible in $R[x]$.

So factorization does not appear to be unique in $R[x]$. But I read on wikipedia (which may be wrong), that if $R$ is a UFD, then $R[x]$ is a UFD.

I must have a misunderstanding because $R = \mathbb{F}_7$ is a UFD, but we have shown two distinct factorizations of a polynomial in $R[x]$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $k[x]$ is indeed a UFD when $k$ is a field.  your $h_1$ is not a factorization (look at the highest order terms).  if you mean to have $3x^2+3x+1$ as a factor of $h_2$, then you should notice that all youve done is move a factor of $3$ around.

Comment: yoyo - I don't quite understand; if we expand both $h_1$ and $h_2$, mod 7, we get $h$. Why wouldn't this be a factorization?

Comment: $h_1$ is not a factorization of $h$ since the leading term for $h_1$ when you expand everything is $3x^4$.

Comment: Ah! I apologize, there is suppose to be a 5 in front of the x^2 in the second quadratic of $h_1$ which I have now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer the question fully, and to elaborate on yoyo's answer, you should notice that $3x^2+3x+4 = 3(x^2+x+6)$, so

$$(3x^2+3x+4)(5x^2+x+5) = (x^2+x+6)(15x^2+3x+15) = (x^2+x+6)(x^2+3x+1)$$

You have basically factored out the unit 3 from one polynomial and moved it to the other one. $R[x]$ being a UFD has not been contradicted.

Comment: Oh excellent! That makes complete sense now, thank you.

Comment: No problem. In general when you have a questionable factorization that doesn't seem quite right, try shifting units around.

Comment: So what would be the correct term for this phenomenon - that factorization is unique "up to multiplication by a unit"?

Comment: @user2521987: Right. You see the same phenomenon even in the integers. E.g. 15 factors into primes in two different ways $(-3) \cdot (-5) = 3 \cdot 5$. In general, prime factorization works in terms of prime *ideals* rather than prime elements, although for certain rings you can always choose a canonical representative from each prime, and make the factorization into prime elements truly unique. In the integers, you always pick the primes to be positive and in polynomial rings over fields you can always pick them to be monic. (in both cases you're also left with an overall unit multiplier)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Factorization is unique up to multiplication by a unit, and reordering of it's factors (we could commute factors and still get the same result written in a different way).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod}\ 7\!:\,\ 3\cdot 5\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, h_1 = fg \,\equiv\,(3f)(5g)\equiv h_2$